# ASP.NET gives error 403 after publishing, but not during development

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I know the hosting provider is using Windows Server 2016 64-bit (so presumably they're also using IIS 10).  The version of .NET they are using is 4.6.2.

I'm getting the error regardless of whether or not the application pool it running.  SSL is entirely disabled.  I have scoured the internet for answers to this only to find outdated answers to this exact same question for previous versions of the server written years ago.  Alot of the answers were not coherent and lacked detail.

I'm entirely at a loss.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Also, I dont have complete access to the IIS server.  I have access to a subset of its options available through a Plesk Control Panel.

Comment: You might want to add what your seeing in Chrome Tools (F12 to show the tools)  to your question.  It might give others more insight into your problem.  Is this only happening to your home page?  Do other URLs within your web site also return 403 (think of a url deeper than the home page).

Comment: Please refer to http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/fix-502-error-asp-net-core.aspx. Please read the tutorial, it seems it might be that your hosting provider doesn't support latest .net core or maybe you haven't published your files properly.